# Network usage data between every two pairs of docker containers

Tags: docker, cadvisor

I have a few micro-services running in docker containers (One service in each container).

How do I find out the network usage between every two pair of docker containers? So that I can make a graph such that I have containers as vertices and on edges I have the amount of bytes transmitted/received.

I used cAdvisor, but it gives me the overall network usage of each container.

Answer (score 0):

Start with docker stats:

```
$ docker stats
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
a645ca0d8feb        wp_wordpress_1      0.00%               135.5MiB / 15.55GiB   0.85%               12.2MB / 5.28MB     2.81MB / 9.12MB     11
95e1649c5b79        wp_db_1             0.02%               203MiB / 15.55GiB     1.28%               6.44MB / 3.11MB     0B / 1.08GB         30
```

Comment: This appears to be giving the general stats as well (i.e with respect to a single container). I wanted stats that show interaction of containers with each other (e.g the number of bytes transferred between every pair of containers).

Comment: The next step I can offer is istio see:
     https://github.com/istio/istio